# How to create an enum of custom classes?

Tags: c#, enums

I have 4 groups of controls on my form, and I would like to bundle each control group into its own class and then be able to enumerate the groups, something like

```
class Group1
{
    public static Label label = form.Lbl1;
    public static Panel panel = form.pnl1;
}

class Group2
{ 
    public static Label label = form.lbl2;
    public static Panel panel = form.pnl2;
}
```

etc through group4... then...

```
enum Groups
{
    Group1,
    Group2,
    Group3,
    Group4
}
```

that way instead of having to write something like

```
lbl1.Visible = true;
lbl2.Visible = true;
```

etc... I could just write

```
foreach (Group group in Groups) 
{
    group.label.visible = true;
}
```

and be done with it. I know I could create a single Group class and then instantiate four instances and make assignments, add them to a List and then do a foreach on the list, but is there a way to do this without instantiating stuff?

==UPDATE==
I've found something that works how I want it to work but I don't know if its good practice or not. I'm sure my rookie coding skills are going to shine through here!

On my Form.Designer.cs I changed the modifiers on my panels from

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel myPanel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel myPanel2;
```

to

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.Panel myPanel1;
public static System.Windows.Forms.Panel myPanel2;
```

Then in my Form.cs file I added the class and child classes...

```
class ControlGroups 
{
    public static class Group1
    {
        public static Panel panel = Form.myPanel1;
    }

    public static class Group2
    {
        public static Panel panel = Form.myPanel2;
    }
}
```

Later on in my code I could do

```
ControlGroups.Group1.panel.Visible = true;
ControlGroups.Group2.panel.Visible = true;
```

and everything compiled just fine.

Is there a way that I can do a foreach on ControlGroups? Such as

```
foreach (Class group in ControlGroups.Subclasses) {
    group.panel.Visible = true;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your main aim was to achieve `foreach (Group group in Groups) ` why use enum? store the class objects in an array and access each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is with an array/list:

Create a class:

```
class GroupClass
{
      public Label labelValue { get; set;}
      public Panel panelValue { get; set;}
}
```

Create objects of the class to store the values:

```
GroupClass first_group = new GroupClass();
first_group.labelValue = form.Lbl1;
first_group.panelValue = form.pnl1;

GroupClass second_group = new GroupClass();
second_group.labelValue = form.Lbl2;
second_group.panelValue = form.pnl2;
```

Add these group objects to list:

```
List<GroupClass> listOfGroups = new List<GroupClass>();
listOfGroups.Add(first_group);
listOfGroups.Add(second_group);
```

Then do foreach:

```
foreach (GroupClass groupObj in listOfGroups ) 
{
    groupObj.labelValue.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks LNS for your response LNS. I know I can do it like this but in my last paragraph I asked if there was a way to do it without creating class instances. I understand enum isn't appropriate but the feature I like about enums is that they dont need to be instantiated.

Comment: I've updated my question with a better example of what I'm trying to do. I would appreciate your input!

Comment: @user2320861 Hm, the thing is you can kind of achieve it, but a foreach loop will require you to iterate through an object reference in this case. Using reflection you can think to iterate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480279/iterate-through-properties-of-static-class-to-populate-list

Comment: Thanks for your input. I checked out that link and I think it gets close but I can't figure out how to access the members in the foreach loop, because the foreach variable will be "typed" at runtime. Anyways, I think the list method is the path of least resistance at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a universal placeholder, if all your groups hold same components.

```
class Group
{
    public Label Label { get; set; }
    public Panel Panel { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var group1 = new Group() { Label = label1, Panel = panel1 };
...
var groups = List<Group> { group1, ... };
```

and us it like

```
foreach (var g in groups)
    g.Label.Visible = false;
```

Enum is not a convenient tool for such a purpose. You are seeking a collection of similar objects (basically same or with a same base at least).