# Unable to Call GetType() on Static Class

Tags: c#, oop, static, compiler-errors

I have the following `Globals` class in the `NewStarterTool` namespace:

```
static class Globals
{
    static internal class FieldNames
    {
        public const string FirstName = "FirstName";
        public const string MiddleInitial = "_3f304008_6d27_46e4_82e1_81d2ea5d5d84";
        public const string LastName = "__x007b_39b5c34f_247a_466c_8a76_480f54461087_x007d_";
        public const string Role = "__x007b_c0bc5325_2cdb_4b7d_8687_eba9cf958f01_x007d_";
        public const string Department = "Department";
        public const string JobTitle = "JobTitle";
        public const string Office = "_38bb16d7_d38b_4409_aa54_25bd0cb921af";
        public const string ReportingTo = "_398dc3c8_ff1d_4013_a6e0_139809b37b0d";
        public const string SecretaryTo = "_cefdf77c_5767_4539_aa5b_098aa3ff0b60";
        public const string StartDate = "StartDate";
        public const string FullTime = "_96d926ba_0a82_4773_964a_43d884e5d6d4";
    }
}
```

In that same namespace, I have a `WPF` form, where I want the `Initialise()` method to iterate around all of the `FieldNames` properties for each item retrieved from `SharePoint`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Initialise();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Initialise()
    {
        var siteUrl = "http://MySharePointSite/SubSiteName/";
        var listName = "TestList";
        var camlQuery = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";

        var listItemCollection = SharePoint.GetListItems(siteUrl, listName, camlQuery);

        foreach (var item in listItemCollection)
        {
            foreach (var property in Globals.FieldNames.GetType().GetProperties())
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, on the line `foreach (var property in Globals.FieldNames.GetType().GetProperties())`, I am seeing this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()'

Even though I can see that both `Globals` and `FieldNames` are both static and therefore should't be causing this error.

---

I can confirm that this works without any issues:

```
var dept = Globals.FieldNames.Department;
```

I tried changing `FieldNames` to:

```
public static class FieldNames
```

I also tried changing the method signature to:

```
private static void Initialise()
```

But both with the same result.

---

Why is this happening?

How can I iterate around the properties of `FieldNames`?

Comment: `typeof(Globals.FieldNames).GetProperties()`

Comment: duplicate of "how to iterate static properties": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480279/iterate-through-properties-of-static-class-to-populate-list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your class is static and GetTypes() is an instance member.

As already noted, you could use `typeof(Globals.FieldNames).GetProperties()`.

Except that that won't work either because you don't have properties. Your values of interest are all fields.

So you will need `typeof(Globals.FieldNames).GetFields()`.

And from each FieldInfo you can then get the value with `(string) field.GetValue(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
foreach (var property in Globals.FieldNames.GetType().GetProperties())
```

you treat `FieldNames` like an object with a method call and there is no static method `FieldNames.GetType()`.

But you can use

```
foreach (var property in typeof(Globals.FieldNames).GetProperties())
```

instead.